# How to show hidden files (.*) in Java app's open file dialog on Linux?

Tags: linux, java

I have an Java application (JabRef to be specific) on Linux OS (Fedora 22), and I want to open a file under a hidden directory (one beginning with dot). But in the open file dialog, I cannot find how to show (and preferably toggle show/hide) hidden files and directories. Is there a key shortcut or so?

I'd like to make it work on 1) [GNOME Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRzZv.png) and 2) [FVWM (no DE)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZoPB.png).

Comment: In Ubuntu/Debian `Ctrl-H` toggles the display of hidden files in both the file manager and open-file dialogues. It may work in Fedora too.

Comment: This is desktop environment dependent.  What are you using?

Comment: @Paul I care about two: 1) Fvwm, no DE 2) GNOME Shell. In 2) I can type the full path but cannot show hidden files in the file list window. In 1) there is no place to type :(

Comment: The Java file chooser by default doesn't show "hidden" files; the application needs to enable the showing of hidden files in the file chooser. It's possible another LaF (look and feel) will allow hidden files to be shown (e.g., a native look and feel might open a native file dialog? perhaps with options to reveal hidden files? it's a long shot); otherwise, you may have to create a symbolic link to the hidden directory in order to navigate into the hidden directory. (May want to open a bug against the project as well.)

Comment: @michael_n Thanks for the explanation! (My current walkaround is to supply the file path in the command line.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Ah... I find JabRef does offer an option to make it possible.)

In JabRef, Select from the menu `Options - Preferences`. Then go to 'Advanced' tab, in the `File dialog` section, and check the option `Use native file dialog`. Then JabRef will use the native file dialog (in my case GTK+ dialog), which can toggle the display of hidden files in the right-click menu.

For general Java applications, as @michael_n pointed out in the comments, the applications need to enable the showing of hidden files in the file chooser.